# algorithm to create a char array from permutations list in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm sorry for the slightly confusing title, I'm unsure of how to phrase it.

I need to create a char array allowing for every possible permutation of a character set.

If I were to give you:

```
char[] charSet = {"a", "b", "c"};
BigInteger value = n; //where n is a number >= 0
char[] charArray = createCharArray(value, charSet);
```

How can I create charArray from value and charSet such that if I ran:

```
createCharArray(new BigInteger("6"), {"a", "b", "c"});
```

it would return {"a", "c"}
because

- a=1
- b=2
- c=3
- aa=4
- ab=5
- ac=6

Here's what I have so far:

```
private char[] createCharArray(BigInteger value, char[] charSet){
    List<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

    if (value.compareTo(this.max) == 0)
        System.out.println("");

    BigInteger csSize = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(charSet.length));

    if(this.powers.isEmpty())
        this.powers.add(0, csSize.pow(0));
    if(this.sumPowers.isEmpty())
        this.sumPowers.add(0, csSize.pow(0));

    BigInteger curPow;
    int i = 1;


    while((curPow = csSize.pow(i)).compareTo(value) <= -1){
        if(this.powers.size() <= i)
            this.powers.add(i, curPow);

        if(this.sumPowers.size() <= i)
            this.sumPowers.add(i, this.sumPowers.get(i-1).add(curPow)); 

        i += 1;
    }

    i -= 1;


    while (i >= 0 && value.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) >= 0){
        if (i <= 1){
            int charNum = value.divide(this.sumPowers.get(0)).intValue() - 1;
            charArray.add(charSet[charNum]);
        }
        else{
            int charNum = value.divide(this.sumPowers.get(i-1).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).intValue() - 1;
            charArray.add(charSet[charNum]);
        }
        value = value.subtract(this.powers.get(i));
        i -= 1;
    }

    char[] returnArray = new char[charArray.size()];

    int j = 0;

    while(j<charArray.size()){
        returnArray[j] = charArray.get(j);
        j += 1;
    }


    return returnArray;
}
```

It certainly could use some help, as a value of 0 fails, values of 1 and 2 succeed, 3-8 fail, 9, 10 succeed, etc.

EDIT: To be clear, the value parameter must be able to be ANY number n > 0. This is why I've chosen BigInteger

Comment: Little nitpick: that is not the definition of "permutation". All permutations of a set of three elements contain always three elements. There are only six permutations for a set of three elements, which is 3! = 3*2*1.

Comment: what's a better word then?

Comment: At the above question: Variation.

Comment: very cool. I'll remember that for the future. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but Variation isn't the correct word neither, still thinking about a good word.

Comment: Why do you use BigInteger? Isn't int a more suitable value holder?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Actually looking into wikipedia it seems the correct terms is `partial permutation`. However, I got confused, because those are called variations in my country and Russia

Comment: In dutch, we call it "repetitional variation" which has the formula p^n, but what we call a variation is n!/p!.

Comment: @Averroes yes generally it would be, however, I might need to have values much larger than an int, or even a long. This could have a size in the trillions and a long is only good until the 4 billions, and int only to half that.

Comment: long goes up to approx. 9.22 * 10^18, much more than 4 billion (into the quintillions).  If long only went up to int.MAX_VALUE * 2 would mean long was only 1 bit longer than int.

Comment: ah you're correct. I looked on wikipedia and mis-read the chart. still the point remains that long is eventually bounded, and I'd like to have the only bound be running out of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after much thinking and eventually breaking it down to using numbers 0-9 instead of characters. Here's the breakdown: Think about how regular base 10 numerals are created.

The number 194 is made up of a 4 in the ones column, a 9 in the tens, and a 1 in the hundreds. The difference between ones, tens, and hundreds is multiplication/division by 10, which is the base.

So I figured that I could mod the 194 by the base (10) to get 4, the ones. then divide by 10 to remove the ones column. mod again to get 9, then divide by 10, mod again to get 1, divide by 10. once the division creates a number that is exactly 0, we are done. This is because we cannot make a number 000194.

For my function, My base is the length of the character set, and the value is like 194 in the example above.

```
private static void createCharArray(BigInteger value, char[] charSet){
    List<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

    BigInteger csSize = BigInteger.valueOf(charSet.length);

    if (value.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0)
        charArray.add(0, charSet [0]);
    else{
        BigInteger modded = value.mod(csSize);
        BigInteger digit  = value.divide(csSize);

        while (modded.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0 || digit.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0){
            if(modded.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0){
                charArray.add(0, charSet[csSize.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).intValue()]);
                value = value.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
            else
                charArray.add(0, charSet[modded.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).intValue()]);
            value = value.divide(csSize);

            modded = value.mod(csSize);
            digit  = value.divide(csSize);
        }
    }

    for(char c : charArray)
        System.out.print(c);
    System.out.println();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    String characters = "";
    characters += "0123456789";
    characters += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    characters += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    characters += " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";

    char[] cs = characters.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(cs);

    createCharArray(new BigInteger("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"), cs);
    long total = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println("Completed in: " + total + " billionths of a second");
    System.out.println("Completed in: " + total/1000000 + " thousandth(s) of a second");
}
```

If you run this, note that that BigInteger 4 lines from the bottom is 100 characters long. On my machine, it takes only 1/1000 th of a second (1 Millisecond).

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that has two fields:

```
private char letter;
private int value;
public <classname>(char letter){
this.letter = letter;
value = 0;
}
//Setters and getters
```

Then in your main when initializing an array (via for loop) set the value to i + 1 (getting rid of 0)

```
for(int i = 0; i < <yourarray>.length; i ++){
    //Assuming you initialized your objects before
    <yourarray>[i].<setterforvalue>(i + 1);
}
```

And then to calculate them together:

```
for(int i = 0; i < <yourarray>.length; i ++){
    for(int j = 0; j < <yourarray>.length; j ++){
     if(<yourarray>[i] + <yourarray>[j] == <needednumber>){
       //Do what you need to do with the value
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, however your answer is iterative, and should I give in a value that is in the quintillions, this will (even after converting ints to BigIntegers) take an enormous amount of time.